# Why does email need an envelope, and what does the "envelope" mean?

Tags: security, email, smtp, rfc822

What is the exact difference between the envelope and the email in smtp?

Why does the protocol need the envelope? In snail mail, the letter needs not contain addresses and is not visible to the postman (at least that's what you want to believe), so all the routing is made entirely based on the envelope and that is clear to me.

However in e-mail, the letter itself is parseable and has headers such as From: and To:. Why is that not enough to route email? Why do we need an envelope?

And what is the meaning of a divergence between the envelope and the email itself? Does it necessarily mean that someone is trying to game the system, or is it, under certain circumstances (what circumstances?), legal to have a difference between them.

Your clarifications are more than welcome.

Puzzled email receiver.

Comment: But, to continue your snail mail metaphor, most professional letters will contain the sender's and recipient's addresses printed on the letter itself.  Those addresses are not *necessary* for the postman, but are instead a courtesy to the recipient.  So it's sensible that email would work the same way.

Comment: I'd say snail mail itself is not flawless. So I've received a snail mail, opened it, and the letter *claimed* to be from my friend. How do I verify that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The recipient address in the SMTP `RCPT TO:` command is what mail transports use to determine the actual recipient of an email.  The addresses in the To: and Cc: headers are there for mail readers to display to users who the recipients are, but they're not actually used by mail transports.

Most mail clients set the same addresses in SMTP `RCPT TO:` and `MAIL FROM:` commands that they insert in To:, Cc:, and From: headers, so the "envelope" addresses will be the same as the addresses in the headers.

Envelope and header addresses will usually agree for most legitimate mail.  Notable exceptions are Bcc: addresses and mailing lists.

Spammers often forge header addresses to try to avoid spam filters.

Answer (score 12):

The bottom line is that the overhead would be too great. When mail servers are processing millions of messages per day, it's much faster during the SMTP session (The Envelope) when the mail server can process individual commands.

If you didn't use an Envelope, you would have to push the entire message at the SMTP server, before you could find out if the message needs to be rejected. Some messages are quite large (I've seen 100+Meg messages working with GIS images).

By using an Envelope, we can issue specific 1 line commands against the mail server, and the mail server will tell us if we are successful or not, right then and there.

Answer (score 11):

The envelope is used by the SMTP server and the message headers are used by a mail reader as everyone else has said.

What has not been said is that the `RCPT TO:` is used to route the message to a specific user regardless of where the user's name appears in the headers.  The user does not necessarily need to appear in the `To:` or even the `Cc:` headers.  Think of a `Bcc:` where the only thing that the receiver knows is who the message was from.  In this case, the `To:` and `CC:` headers should be empty - hence the *blind* part of BCC.  In another case, if an email message has the user mentioned in the CC list along with 10 other users, how can the SMTP routing pick the appropriate user.  The answer is that it uses the `RCPT` line to route the message.

This is also used when routing via mailing lists.  The To: header will contain the mailing list e-mail address.  An SMTP system will generate separate messages for each user in the list each with a specific `RCPT TO: user@host...` envelope.  In this case, the user's name will not even appear in any of the other headers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 'blind' part means the BCC *itself* is blinded (so the other recipients don't know it was BCC'd.)  The recipient of the BCC doesn't see the `Bcc:`, but they *do* see the `To:` and `Cc:`.  I know because I BCC myself all the time when sending messages from web mail so that I get a permanent record back into my POP client.

Answer (score 2):

An email message is very similar to a physical letter that you would send in the mail. There is an **envelope**, with **To/From** information, and there is the actual letter on the inside, with it's own **To/From** information. The **envelope to/from** information is the real information that is used for message delivery, for both email servers and post offices.

When an **envelope** comes into a post office, they inspect the **To** address on the envelope, and send it to the correct destination. The post office workers have no knowledge of the letter inside the envelope. The letting inside could have completely different To/From information than the envelope says. The Envelope could say the message is to Bob, but the letter inside may say it's for Alice. Or in real world: The envelope could say the message is to *SomeCompanyName*, and when secretary open envelope, letter inside say, it's is for Mr. Brown which work in *SomeCompanyName*.

Source: [Email Envelope vs Email Header](https://www.mybluelinux.com/what-is-email-envelope-and-email-header/)